# understanding jQuery parent, children and sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to figure out where I am going with the current show and hide function I am trying to incorporate on my site. I have a drop down menu show and hide function similar to the one currently implemented at [Hippodrome Mobile Casino](https://www.hippodromeonline.com/). Which is identical to my HTML.  My div class I am noticing with my Jquery when i click the next button `.regNext` it hides all three `.regGroupContent` divs. However i want to add and remove the `active class` which i current have as `display:none` on my site.

```
$('.regGroupContent').removeClass('active');
$('.regGroupContent').eq(0).addClass('active');

$('.regNext').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.regGroupContent').hide().removeClass('active');
    $this.parent().children($('.regGroupContent')).show().addClass('active');
});
```

Html

```
<div class="vengeForm">
         <div class="regGroupContent">
             <div class ="fieldset">
                 <ul class="fieldset">
                     <li class="editor-next">
                         <a href="#" class="regNext"></a>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Could you post your markup and/or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing the problem?

Comment: I for one am not going to some randomly (to me) linked site to investigate HTML markup etc. just to answer a question.

Comment: `Var $this` ? - Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss it is not a cap V dude!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, what I suspected - likely a paste error.

Comment: Clarify please that you have `.active {display:none}` CSS as your text description seems to indicate.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  yes i .active as {display:none}

Answer (score 4):

This line has a bit of a syntax issue:

```
$this.parent().children($('.regGroupContent')).show().addClass('active');
```

In the `children` selector, you don't need a jQuery object, rather just the class name. Also, your `.parent()` selector is only going one level up, you need to get to the top of the element tree. Try changing it to:

```
$this.parents('.vengeForm').children('.regGroupContent').show().addClass('active');
```

Comment: Furthermore, `.siblings('.regGroupContent')` is equivalent to `.parent().children('.regGroupsContent')`

Comment: You'll have to post the HTML here then so we can look at it deeper

Comment: tymeJV..give me 10mins i will post the html up

Comment: @tymeJV html has been posted

Comment: @tymeJV Grrrrr! not even that works. once you click on .regNext it hides all the children, instead of showing one by one.

Comment: warning: the comment by @package is not entirely correct:
`.siblings(x)` does NOT include self, whereas 
`.parent().children(x)` does include self.